# JQuery - Listas "sortables"

Tags: html, jquery, html5, jquery-ui, blade

intento hacer dos listas con JqueryUI que sean sortables y se pueda hacer drag and drop entre ellas.

Para ellos tengo el "head" de mi plantilla blade de esta forma, donde cargo jquery y jqueryUI

```
{{--JQUERY--}}
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

{{--DRAG AND DROP JQUERY--}}
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Luego voy al archivo donde quiero poner las listas y tengo este código

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#sortable').sortable();
        $('#sortable').disableSelection();
    });
</script>
```

Las listas las creo de esta forma

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li>
    <h1>Titular de la noticia 1</h1>
    <p>1234</p>
</li>
<li>
    <h1>Titular de la noticia 2</h1>
    <p>1234</p>
</li>
```

Y el error que me da al cargar la página es este.

Por más que busco en esta página, la gente dice que poniendo primero Jquery.js y luego Jquery-ui debe funcionar, pero eso ya lo hago.

Gracias,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el HTML donde tengas el elemento con id "sortable"?

Comment: Gracias, he añadido el código de las listas

Answer (score 0):

He usado tu código y me ha funcionado correctamente, quizas el problema venga en la manera que en la que montas el html completo, yo lo hice así y lo he probado en Firefox y Chrome sin problemas:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="sortable" style="cursor:move;">
            <li>
                <h1>Titular de la noticia 1</h1>
                <p>1234</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h1>Titular de la noticia 2</h1>
                <p>1234</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#sortable').sortable();
                $('#sortable').disableSelection();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```